# Ajax Call, how to access $_POST var

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

Sorry if this is a silly question but I'm completely new to AJAX and I'm wondering why my code is not working like I want..

I have the following:

an Ajax Call looking like that:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/newnote.php",
                    data: {
                        content: content
                    },
                    success: function() {
                    }
                });
```

and on the beginning of the page newnote.php (which is exactly the one, where the ajax-call is on, I have the following PHP:

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
    header("Location:index.php");
}
```

But the php on the beginning of the page is not executed, of course, because the site seems not to be reloaded, but, when looking in developer tools under "network", i see that there is a post request on newnote.php with the values I want. But the question is: How can I access them? So for example, if I post the following data: `content: "test"`, that I can write in PHP sth. like `<?=$_POST['content'];?>`... So how can I access the $_POST-Data from AJAX? Do I need to refresh the page or how does this work?

Thanks for your help

Comment: just send an additional query like submitted=true and check if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){//code}

Comment: I think you are confusing yourself unnecessarily. All your `newnote.php` does is to forward any POST-request to `index.php`. So if you want to get any sensible response look into that file.

Comment: I also noticed that even if you get something sensible back your Ajax call is not equipped with a success function that receives the data. Check out the jquery doc http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: hengecyche: that's what I'm doing, but it's not jumping into the if case (so the statement is "false")
@cars10 the header was just an example (even if it doesn't execute the header, because my $_POST[]-array seems to be always empty.. what I want is just accessing the data, sent by ajax..

Comment: try print_r or var_dump of $_POST and comment here

Comment: You cannot use AJAX to to point to PHP in the same file as the AJAX request. See [the basics](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html) as well as more [advanced example](http://jayblanchard.net/putting_it_all_together.html).

Comment: well $_POST is array and if you just want access passed queries use foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){//query=value}

Comment: the result of var_dump is just array(0) { }

@JayBlanchard if this is true, than that could be the problem...

Comment: seems yo found the root of your problem

Answer (score -1):

after exchanging I now got the question: 
to access to your code you must use the callback of your ajax call

```
success: function(result){ 
    $("#div1").html(result); // here you put the content that echoes your php inside your div1 on the actual page without reload 
}
```

On the php side where the content is posted you must echo something that will be caught by this ajax call

Comment: Sorry, but that was not what I wanted... I post data with ajax, but I don't know how to access that data then (with php), because the site isn't reloaded or something, I just can see the request in the network tab of my developer console

Comment: il you use a header right after your post, you ll be automatically redirected and the post data will dissapear as the redirection have posted nothing.

Comment: and with ajax or without ajax, it is the same on the server side, you ll get your data as posted with a html form : $_POST{"content"]

Comment: Header was just an example, to show you, that my $_POST-Array is empty when checking (because there is no redirection)... What I want is something like echoing the content of $_POST['content'], but it seems to be empty when checking, because the page is not reloaded by the request...

Comment: well thats the basic idea of the ajax, it is to not reload the actual page.
you need to post on a page, and grab the callback after the php page did its  work

Comment: I see that, but why can't I access the variable then? so `<?=$_POST['content'];?>` doesn't print any text...

Comment: you have to use the success function :
 success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result); // here you put the content that echoes your php inside your div1 on the actual page without reload
    }

Comment: But in that case, AJAX is just useless, isn't it? If I just want to change the content, I can use JQuery to just change it, but I want to be able to access the variable with php...

Comment: well if you want to have your content in php ( to save it in db for example), then you must use ajax. If you want some content in php, you have to post it so here ajax is cool because you can stay on the page while posting it

Comment: AJAX isn't useless if used for things it is designed for. You just need to understand what it does a bit better and you'll be finding uses for it in no time.

Comment: damn i try to help, and i got a downvote, faith in humanity... reaching 0. I m out :'(

Comment: It wasn't me downvoting.. However, there is no possiibility to access the content of $_POST[], if the ajax request is on the same page I want to access it in php?

Comment: it is still possible, but i d suggest you to post on a little php file which is only processing the action AFTER the post. create a newnote_post.php, post your data on this page and do the treatment in this file. After your treatment echo what you want to echo ( nothing if all had to be made in php) and thats it.

Comment: @JayBlanchard how? So how should I redirect on the page including sending POST-Data?

Comment: Your form should include `method="post` with the action of the form being blank or referring to itself. Filling out the form and clicking submit will populate the `$_POST` array. Once you have processed your data from the POST, perform the redirect. These are the basics of PHP forms @user3375021